# How to send a command to a Linux Shell through ssh; Store the output as a variable; But do NOT print the output to the console

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I am working on a project in C# and WPF that involves sending commands to a Linux shell, and performing checks on the outputs from said commands.  My project creates an ssh connection using Renci.ssh, automatically sends various commands, and prints the results to a console output window in a GUI I created.

I have several methods which, together, send commands to the Linux shell and returns the response (see below).

```
    private ShellStream _ss;
    private SshClient   _sc;
    private bool _isConnected;

    public string SendReceive(string cmd, Regex expect, int numSec)
    {
        var r = "";
        try
        {
            Send(cmd);
            r = WaitFor(expect, numSec);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Caught exception after sending cmd=" + cmd, ex);
            return "";
            // throw (ex);
        }
        return r;
    }

    public void Send(string cmd)
    {
        if (!_isConnected) throw new NotConnectedException(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) ? "Can't send, connection not connected" : $"{Name} is not connected, can't send");
        try
        {
            Flush(33); // flush anything in read buffer.
            _ss.Write(cmd);
            // Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(33)).Wait(); // give ccap time to catch up.
            _ss.Write("\r");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Not able to send text= " + cmd, ex);
            // throw (ex);
        }
    }

    public string WaitFor(Regex expect, int numSec)
    {
        if (!_isConnected) throw new NotConnectedException(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) ? "Can't receive, connection not connected" : $"{Name} is not connected.");
        var r = "";
        try
        {
            r = Filter(_ss.Expect(expect, numSec));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Caught exception waiting for response. ", ex);
            return "";
        }
        return r;
    }
```

When these methods are implemented, commands are sent in the following format:

```
var send = Conn.SendReceive("command text", expected_regex, 10);
```

This stores both the sent command & the entire output in *send* and also prints both (command & output) to the console.  The problem is, the output of certain commands is far too long to print in my GUI console.  This makes it very difficult to review the console content.

In general, I am trying to check if the output of certain commands contains a specified string.  Some other occasions involve needing to store the output of one command to be used in a different command.

I cannot use linux tools like |grep or |awk to limit my output.  This is because the command is also stored in the *send* variable.  Thus any "specified string" search parameters I tell |grep or |awk to look for will be included in *send*.  So if I use:

```
if (send.Contains("Specified String"))
```

"Specified String" will always be found, regardless of whether or not |grep found it in the output.

Is there a way so send a command to Linux, print just the command in console, store the output as a variable in the C# code for use, BUT do NOT print the output to the console?